# Using Textbox.Text as Value in Datatrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatrigger

I'am new to XAML and WPF and im facing a problem with the Datatrigger. I have a Textbox with e.g. "2012" as text. Now I want to highlight Rows in a Datagrid with this specific year. Its working with Value="2012", but I want it to be checked every time the Textbox changes.

Is it possible to somehow get the "Textbox.Text" into that Datatrigger Value?

The reason behind this is to give the User some kind of optical feedback where to find these Years in my datagrid.

```
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Year}" Value="2012">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8EBB3F"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
```

I already tried to use a local class / resource, but it didnt work for "Values"

```
<local:Year x:Key="myDataSource" val="2012"/>
```

I hope its clear what I'am trying to achieve :)

Thank You

PS: Sorry I'am not used to write in english anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Binding` to `ElementName` in `DataTrigger` like this (for `TextBox` named `tbTest`).

```
Value="{Binding ElementName=tbTest, Path=Text}"
```